# Log upstream service in nginx load balancer log

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have 2 nginx webservers with a nginx load balancer spliting the load.
I am trying to log to which webserver was a request sent into the log file `/var/log/nginx/access.log` but I can't find such option in [ngx_http_log_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) docs.

Any idea if this is possible and how to do it?

Comment: [`$upstream_addr`](http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_addr)

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).